# Turning a dataframe into multiple graphs in R

Tags: r, data-manipulation

I have a `data.frame` that looks like this:

```
    row.names   id  actor       event      time end
    4427    1494    Locke23rus  merged      1   1
    4428    1494    Locke23rus  closed      1   1
    4429    1494    Locke23rus  referenced  1   1
    4492    1397    brixen      discussed   2   2
    4493    1397    brixen      closed      2   2
    ...
```

A complete dataset can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/aronlindberg/47456af8d35426d7873a). Next, load data and libraries:

```
dat <- my data # i.e. the data above
library(plyr)
library(network)
```

Using the following function (as suggested by @hrbrmstr) I can transform this data into a network graph object:

```
makeNetwork <- function(dat)
{
  dat2 <<- ddply(dat, .(id), function(d){
    data.frame(
      event = d$event[-1],
      from = d$actor[-NROW(d)],
      to = d$actor[-1],
      time = paste(d$time[-NROW(d)], d$time[-1], sep = "-")
    )
    })
  dat3 <- cbind(dat2["from"], dat2["to"])
  dat4 <- as.network(dat3[, 1:2])
  (dat4)
}
```

However, I'd like to cut out only the rows of the initial dataset that has the same id, run the network graph generation code on each set of rows with common ids, and then put the resulting network graph objects in a list, like so:

```
list(graph_object_id1494, graph_object_id1397, ...)
```

So I run:

```
graph_list <- dlply(dat, .(id), .fun=makeNetwork)
```

which generates the following error message:

```
Error in `[.data.frame`(dat2, "from") : undefined columns selected
```

How can I properly create a list of graph objects?

Comment: Where is `as.network` defined as a function? Or is it from a package?

Comment: `library(network)` - updated the code, sorry about that.

Comment: `install.packages("network")`

Comment: Possibly as straightforward as wrapping your generation code into a function (say, `makeNetwork`) and then doing a `dlply(dat, .(id), .fun=makeNetwork)`? which will do the split by common id and return the results in a list? (not tried it but that's the approach I'd take; cld also use `by` but you're already using `plyr` functions)

Comment: Could you just do `lapply(split(dat, dat$id), as.network)`?

Comment: @hrbrmstr, I tried `dlply(dat, .(id), .fun=makeNetwork)`, however, it seems that the transferring of variables from functions within functions are tripping me up. Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I can make it work:

```
# Make a raw graph dataset
makeNetworkData <- function(dat)
{
  dat2 <- ddply(dat, .(id), function(d){
    data.frame(
      event = d$event[-1],
      from = d$actor[-NROW(d)],
      to = d$actor[-1],
      time = paste(d$time[-NROW(d)], d$time[-1], sep = "-")
      )
     })
}

# apply function to make a list
graph_list <- dlply(dat, .(id), makeNetworkData)

# delete all data.frames (entries in the list) where nrow()=0
nr <- sapply(graph_list, nrow)
graph_list <- graph_list[nr > 0]

makeNetworkGraph <- function(graph_list){
  output <- as.network(graph_list[, 3:4], loops = TRUE)
  (output)
}

# Turn raw data in list to graph objects
graph_objects <- llply(graph_list, makeNetworkGraph)

# apply any SNA statistic to all entries in the list
hierarchy_list <- llply(graph_objects, hierarchy, measure="krackhardt")
```